# Denominate the amount with the minimum number of coins with a given face value. Greedy problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, greedy, coin-change

I have the C++ function to do. It works fine, but there are some cases where it works bad - "greedy problem".

My C++ code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> ans;

std::vector<int> get_change(const std::vector<int> &denominations, int amount) {
    //pure algo
    std::vector<int> money = denominations;
    std::vector<int> count;
    ans.clear();
    count.assign(money.size(), 0);
    std::sort(money.begin(), money.end());
    int summ = amount;
    for (int i = count.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        count[i] = summ / money[i];
        summ = summ % money[i];
        if (summ==0)
            break;
    }


    //ans generation
    for (int i = 0; i < money.size(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < count[i]; j++)
            ans.push_back(money[i]);
    return ans;
}
```

Greedy problem sample: `get_change({ 1, 6, 9 }, 30)` will return `{ 1, 1, 1, 9, 9, 9 }`, but not `{ 6, 6, 9, 9 }`.

The task is to improve this algorithm to get the same answer.

Comment: your algorithm is not correct. What is the question?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 He means how to get `{6,6,9,9}`

Comment: This is asking for minimum number of coins needed to make the total. So loop over from 1 to 30. Inside that loop over on `{1,6,9}` and keep collecting the minimal coins needed using `dp[i] = Math.min(dp[i],dp[i-coins[j]] + 1)` . Since you have infinite supply, bothering after frequency of each coin is eliminated anyway. While doing `dp[i] = Math.min(dp[i],dp[i-coins[j]] + 1)`, maintain another array which contains the set of numbers added.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 sure, my question was how to improve this algorithm to get same answer.

Comment: @vivek_23 I appreciate your participation, and I sure you can write the whole correct answer! By the way, numbers' order isn't matter.

Comment: Backtracking algorithm is also possible.

Comment: I am a bit caught up. You can look for coin change problem online to get a clue.

Comment: Greedy algorithms don't work here. You need to replace the algorithm, not to improve it.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. sure, I remember rules of SO: TC should send own ideas and own summary. So, which algorithm can we use? But the question remains open.

Comment: @vivek_23 I found something online, but it is not helped me...

Comment: @Damien May be! Can you please explain your idea?

Comment: Dynamic programming should work.

Comment: @D7ILeucoH Ok, I will let you know soon.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. what kind of dynamic programming? Can you give a sample?

Comment: @vivek_23 yes, please, it should be interesting to take into account different ways

Comment: @vivek_23 that's okay!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach is backtracking.

Backtracking is a general algorithm for finding all (or some) solutions to some computational problems, notably constraint satisfaction problems, that incrementally builds candidates to the solutions, and abandons a candidate ("backtracks") as soon as it determines that the candidate cannot possibly be completed to a valid solution. (Wikipedia)

Here, we try to determine the number of coins, for each coin.

The candidates are abandonned, as soon as the total number of coins is higher than the current optimal solution. Moreover, here, in a given situation (at step `i`), we directly calculate the maximum number of coins for `coins[i]`, such that the total sum is not higher than the amount.

Here is a possible implementation:

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <vector>
#include    <algorithm>

std::vector<int> get_change(const std::vector<int>& denominations, int amount) {
    std::vector<int> coins = denominations;
    std::vector<int> n_coins(coins.size(), 0);
    std::vector<int> n_coins_opt(coins.size(), 0);
    int n = coins.size();

    std::sort(coins.begin(), coins.end(), std::greater<int>());

    int sum = 0;    // current sum
    int i = 0;      // index of the coin being examined
    int n_min_coins = amount / coins[n - 1] + 1;
    int n_total_coins = 0;
    bool up_down = true;

    while (true) {          // UP
        if (up_down) {
            n_coins[i] = (amount - sum) / coins[i];     // max number of coins[i]
            sum += n_coins[i] * coins[i];
            n_total_coins += n_coins[i];
            if (sum == amount) {
                if (n_total_coins < n_min_coins) {
                    n_min_coins = n_total_coins;
                    n_coins_opt = n_coins;
                }
                up_down = false;
                sum -= n_coins[i] * coins[i];
                n_total_coins -= n_coins[i];
                n_coins[i] = 0;
                i--;
            }
            else {
                if (i == (n - 1) || (n_total_coins >= n_min_coins)) {   // premature abandon
                    sum -= n_coins[i] * coins[i];
                    n_total_coins -= n_coins[i];
                    n_coins[i] = 0;
                    up_down = false;
                    i--;
                }
                else {
                    i++;
                }
            }

        }
        else {            // DOWN
            if (i < 0) break;
            if (n_coins[i] == 0) {
                if (i == 0) break;
                i--;
            }
            else {
                sum -= coins[i];
                n_coins[i] --;
                n_total_coins--;
                i++;
                up_down = true;
            }
        }
    }

    std::vector<int> ans;

    for (int i = 0; i < coins.size(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n_coins_opt[i]; j++)
            ans.push_back(coins[i]);

    return ans;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> coins = { 1, 6, 9 };
    int amount = 30;
    auto n_coins = get_change(coins, amount);

    for (int i = 0; i < n_coins.size(); i++)
            std::cout << n_coins[i] << " ";

    std::cout << "\n";
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Could you provide an input sample that gives an erroneous output?

Comment: Btw, it returns "1 1 6 6". And it falling down to infinity loop at simple test `get_change({ 1 }, 0)`;

Comment: You see, I corrected `main()`. Now it returns `9 9 6 6` and that's good! But we have issue with infinity loop... I hope you can improove other part of code

Comment: I did not take into account that the amount could be zero! No clear that this case could be possible. Just need to add a test `if (amount == 0)`. i will have a look soon

Comment: Btw there are also infinity loop at the `get_change({ 1 }, 3)`

Comment: And now I corrected your function. Initially it should return full answer, not count of each coins. And now it returns full answer, as combination of coins.

Comment: I have a problem with one of your modifications: on my  PC, the programme was returning the good answer, *without* your modification. I will accept your modifications and check. Concerning the issue with one coin only, i see how to correct it.

Comment: Yes, I suppose your function was good, but my question needs a bit other function (other output). Now you can check it. Anyway, now we have to solve the infinity loop problem...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203672/discussion-between-damien-and-d7ileucoh).

Answer (score 1):

This is a [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) problem.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Solution{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception{
            System.out.println(getChange(new int[]{1,6,9},30));
            System.out.println(getChange(new int[]{1},3));
            System.out.println(getChange(new int[]{4,20,500},450));
    }

    private static List<Integer> getChange(int[] denominations,int amount){
            Arrays.sort(denominations);
            List<Integer> ans = new ArrayList<>();
            if(amount <= 0 || denominations[0] > amount) return ans;
            int[][] dp = new int[amount + 1][2];

            for(int i=0;i<denominations.length;++i){
                if(denominations[i] > amount) break;
                dp[denominations[i]][0] = 1;
                dp[denominations[i]][1] = 0;
                for(int j=denominations[i] + 1;j<=amount;++j){
                    if(dp[j-denominations[i]][0] > 0 && (dp[j][0] == 0 || dp[j-denominations[i]][0] + 1 < dp[j][0])){
                       dp[j][0] = dp[j-denominations[i]][0] + 1;
                       dp[j][1] = j-denominations[i];
                    }
                }
            }

            if(dp[amount][0] > 0){
                while(dp[amount][0] != 0){
                    ans.add(amount - dp[amount][1]);
                    amount = dp[amount][1];
                }
            }



            return ans;
    }
}
```

**Demo:** https://ideone.com/2fYg4F

**Algorithm:**

- This is similar to [coin change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem) problem.
- We first sort the numbers in the array for uniform computation.
- Now, we iterate on all array elements and make each array element loop over all possible amounts from that element till final amount.
- Now, we can make amount `j`(which is a sum) only **if we have made** sum `j - denominations[i]`.
- While doing so, we also check for minimum number of coins needed. If amount `j` with current `denominations[i]` needs lesser coins than the current value stored in `dp[j][0]`, then we update the answer in `dp[j]` accordingly.
- In the end, we just loop over the exact coins needed and return the answer.

**What is dp[][]**:

- It's just a simple 2D array where the 0<sup>th</sup> column keeps track of minimum number of coins 
  needed in it's first index and 2<sup>nd</sup> index has the previous coin index that give it the 
  minimal value.
- The 2<sup>nd</sup> index in dp[][] would ease out the calculation to find the exact coin value as we would have to just do `amount - dp[amount][1]` to get the coin value.

In the end, we just do a check of `dp[amount][0]` value. If it's value is `0`, we don't have a solution, else we compute it.

Answer (score 0):

I am adaptated `vivek_23`'s dynamic solution to required `C++` language.

```
std::vector<int> get_change2(const std::vector<int>& coins, int amount) {
    std::vector<int> denominations = coins;
    std::sort(denominations.begin(), denominations.end());
    std::vector<int> ans;

    if (amount <= 0 || denominations[0] > amount)
        return ans;

    int** dp = new int* [amount + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < amount + 1; i++) {
        dp[i] = new int[2];
        dp[i][0] = 0;
        dp[i][1] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < denominations.size(); i++) {
        if (denominations[i] > amount) break;
        dp[denominations[i]][0] = 1;
        dp[denominations[i]][1] = 0;
        for (int j = denominations[i] + 1; j <= amount; ++j) {
            if (dp[j - denominations[i]][0] > 0 && (dp[j][0] == 0 || dp[j - denominations[i]][0] + 1 < dp[j][0])) {
                dp[j][0] = dp[j - denominations[i]][0] + 1;
                dp[j][1] = j - denominations[i];
            }
        }
    }

    if (dp[amount][0] > 0) {
        while (dp[amount][0] != 0) {
            ans.push_back(amount - dp[amount][1]);
            amount = dp[amount][1];
        }
    }



    return ans;
}
```